# Problem with XFCE lockscreen

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, lock-screen

I tried a bunch of different desktop environments before settling on Cinnamon.

Occasionally, I'll unlock my computer and the XFCE lockscreen shows up. Sometimes it's even on top of my regular lockscreen, so I have to put in my password twice.

How do I get rid of the XFCE lock screen? I've already tried `autoremove` and `apt-get purge xubuntu-desktop`, but as `Xubuntu-desktop` is no longer installed, I get an error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR: You probably want `sudo apt-get remove light-locker light-locker-settings` to remove the xfce lockscreen.

Your issue is that `xubuntu-desktop` is a meta package. Removing it by itself doesn't really do much for you.

When you installed `xubuntu-desktop` you had the option to allow/deny a bunch of other packages being installed. If you've forgotten what packages those are (which, let's face it, why would you remember?) you can figure out what it installed with

```
apt-cache show xubuntu-desktop
```

This will show you a bunch of information about the metapackage. For reference, the results of mine on xubuntu 14.04 looks like so (note, I added the lines of `>>>>>` for emphasis that I explain below):

```
mitch@thapphireth:[/media/mitch/Acer]: apt-cache show xubuntu-desktop
Package: xubuntu-desktop
Priority: optional
Section: universe/metapackages
Installed-Size: 44
Maintainer: Xubuntu Developers <xubuntu-devel@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Source: xubuntu-meta
Version: 2.180
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
Depends: alsa-base, alsa-utils, anacron, bc, ca-certificates, dmz-cursor-theme, doc-base, fonts-dejavu-core, fonts-freefont-ttf, foomatic-db-compressed-ppds, genisoimage, ghostscript-x, gtk2-engines-pixbuf, inputattach, language-selector-gnome, libasound2-plugins, libpam-systemd, libsasl2-modules, libxp6, lightdm, lightdm-gtk-greeter, memtest86+, openprinting-ppds, pm-utils, printer-driver-pnm2ppa, rfkill, software-properties-gtk, thunar, thunar-volman, tumbler, ubuntu-drivers-common, ubuntu-extras-keyring, unzip, update-manager, wireless-tools, wpasupplicant, xdg-user-dirs, xdg-user-dirs-gtk, xfce4-appfinder, xfce4-notifyd, xfce4-panel, xfce4-session, xfce4-settings, xfdesktop4, xfwm4, xkb-data, xorg, xterm, xubuntu-artwork, xubuntu-default-settings, zenity, zip
Recommends: abiword, abiword-plugin-grammar, abiword-plugin-mathview, acpi-support, app-install-data-partner, apport-gtk, apt-offline, avahi-autoipd, avahi-daemon, blueman, bluez, bluez-alsa, bluez-cups, brltty, brltty-x11, catfish, cups, cups-bsd, cups-client, cups-filters, desktop-file-utils, espeak, evince, file-roller, firefox, fonts-droid, fonts-kacst-one, fonts-khmeros-core, fonts-lao, fonts-liberation, fonts-lklug-sinhala, fonts-nanum, fonts-opensymbol, fonts-sil-abyssinica, fonts-sil-padauk, fonts-takao-pgothic, fonts-thai-tlwg, fonts-tibetan-machine, gcc, gigolo, gimp, gmusicbrowser, gnome-accessibility-themes, gnome-calculator, gnome-sudoku, gnome-system-tools, gnomine, gnumeric, gstreamer0.10-plugins-base-apps, gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio, gtk-theme-config, gucharmap, gvfs-backends, gvfs-fuse, hplip, im-config, indicator-application, indicator-messages, indicator-power, indicator-sound, kerneloops-daemon, laptop-detect, libnotify-bin, libnss-mdns, libpam-gnome-keyring, libxfce4ui-utils, light-locker, light-locker-settings, make, menulibre, mousepad, mugshot, network-manager-gnome, network-manager-pptp, network-manager-pptp-gnome, onboard, orage, parole, pastebinit, pavucontrol, pcmciautils, pidgin, pidgin-otr, policykit-desktop-privileges, printer-driver-c2esp, printer-driver-foo2zjs, printer-driver-min12xxw, printer-driver-ptouch, printer-driver-pxljr, printer-driver-sag-gdi, printer-driver-splix, ristretto, simple-scan, software-center, speech-dispatcher, system-config-printer-gnome, thunar-archive-plugin, thunar-media-tags-plugin, thunderbird, transmission-gtk, ttf-indic-fonts-core, ttf-punjabi-fonts, ttf-ubuntu-font-family, update-notifier, whoopsie, xchat, xcursor-themes, xdg-utils, xfburn, xfce4-cpugraph-plugin, xfce4-dict, xfce4-indicator-plugin, xfce4-mailwatch-plugin, xfce4-netload-plugin, xfce4-notes-plugin, xfce4-places-plugin, xfce4-power-manager, xfce4-quicklauncher-plugin, xfce4-screenshooter, xfce4-systemload-plugin, xfce4-taskmanager, xfce4-terminal, xfce4-verve-plugin, xfce4-volumed, xfce4-weather-plugin, xfce4-whiskermenu-plugin, xfce4-xkb-plugin, xubuntu-community-wallpapers, xubuntu-docs, xul-ext-ubufox
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
Filename: pool/universe/x/xubuntu-meta/xubuntu-desktop_2.180_amd64.deb
Size: 3864
MD5sum: 98a121dd1a2b1ced327e0a2a7a7890a1
SHA1: 9422029424ff4f473b2d7fed9f141f1a6b69a728
SHA256: 161cfafb2e43c9c0d75a1bf71884b80ad01f6048f4e85598122d7047514ee5c2
Description-en: Xubuntu desktop system
 This package depends on all of the packages in the Xubuntu desktop system
 .
 It is safe to remove this package if some of the desktop system packages are
 not desired.
Description-md5: 25eeb522d88fba23a532953cbbf1638e
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Origin: Ubuntu
Supported: 3y
Task: xubuntu-desktop
```

Note the two lines between the `>>>>` that I put in. These lines are software packages that installing xubuntu-desktop brought in. This does NOT include software packages that THOSE software packages brought in, etc.

Now, if you wanted to completely purge `xubuntu-desktop` you'd have to uninstall each and every one of those packages, which you probably don't want to do.

Your best solution is this:

1. run `apt-cache show xubuntu-desktop`
2. From the list of Depends/recommends find which pacakges you don't want. For your purposes getting rid of everything that starts with `xfce` will probably remove everything you want. Some of those packages though, like `alsa-base` and `alsa-utils` are important, and you don't want to remove those. Perhaps compare it to the results of `apt-cache show cinnamon`, and remove only what doesn't overlap (but again, be careful even then - you don't want to delete too much).
3. Once you've done all that, run `sudo apt-get autoremove` to clean up any lonely dependencies

That being said, for your actual question you probably want to do `sudo apt-get remove light-locker light-locker-settings`, as those are the xfce/xubuntu-specific lock screen packages.

Comment: Much appreciated. I started just with the packages that contained xfce and xubuntu in their names, plus light-locker and light-locker-settings it seem to have solved the issue.